# How many pairs of points at least on the unit sphere can be used to determine a rotation matrix in $\mathbb{R}^n$ uniquely?

Tags: matrices, rotations

A rotation matrix map the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ onto itself, we want to identify the rotation matrix $R$ by pairs of points $x,x'\in \mathbb{S}^n$, such that
$$
Rx = x'
$$
for $n = 2$, one pair of points is enough, for the general case, is it true that $n-1$ pair of points are enough?

for $n = 3$, using the axis-angle representation of rotation matrix, the axis of rotation passing through the center of the unit sphere and intersecting the unit sphere with $e$, then $d(e,x) = d(e,x')$, that is $e$ must be on the circle that is the intersection of the unit sphere with the perpendicular plane of the segment $xx'$ passing through its middle point. using another pair of points can found another circle, and the point $e$ is the intersection of the two circles. so two pair of points should be enough.

Comment: If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are antipodal and $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ are also antipodal, then there are infinitely many such rotations.

Comment: if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are antipodal, which implies $x_2 = -x_1$? I think the two pairs of points should be independent.

Comment: Yes, $n-1$ linearly independent points are always enough, and fewer points can never limit the rotation to one unique solution. Proof coming tomorrow, if nobody beats me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is always possible to uniquely specify the action with $n-1$ points,  and fewer than $n-1$ points will never uniquely specify a rotation. We can also construct the unique rotation from any set of points that do admit exactly one solution.

For some positive integers $n$ and $k$, suppose we have sequences $A = \{ x_i \}_{1 \leq i \leq k} \subset S^{n-1}$ and $B = \{ x_i' \}_{1 \leq i \leq k} \subset S^{n-1}$, with each sequence containing no repeated vector values. We are interested in the set of all rotation matrices satisfying $Rx_i = x_i'$ for each $1 \leq i \leq k$.

A rotation matrix must preserve distances, or equivalently inner products, meaning for all index pairs $i,j$,

$$\|x_i-x_j\| = \|x_i'-x_j'\| \iff \langle x_i, x_j \rangle$$

If that's not true, there is no solution. For the rest, we'll assume these conditions are always true.

Let $d_A = \dim \mathrm{span}(A)$. Given $A$ and $B$, let $R_{AB}$ be the linear transformation $R_{AB}: \mathrm{span}(A) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by

$$ R_{AB} \sum_{i=1}^k a_i x_i = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i x_i' $$

Note $R_{AB}\, x_i = x_i'$, and the image of $R_{AB}$ is exactly $\mathrm{span}(B)$.

Let $\{b_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq d_A}$ be any orthonormal basis of $\mathrm{span}(A)$. So for some real numbers $\beta_{ij}$ with $1 \leq i$ and $1 \leq j \leq d_A$,

$$ b_i = \sum_{j=1}^k \beta_{ij} x_j $$
$$ \langle b_i, b_j \rangle = \delta_{ij} $$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.

For any two (possibly equal) indices $1 \leq i,j \leq d_s$,

$$ \begin{align*}
\langle R_{AB} b_i, R_{AB} b_j \rangle &= \left\langle R_{AB} \sum_{u=1}^k \beta_{iu} x_u, R_{AB} \sum_{v=1}^k \beta_{jv} x_v \right\rangle \\
\langle R_{AB} b_i, R_{AB} b_j \rangle &= \left \langle \sum_{u=1}^k \beta_{iu} R_{AB} x_u, \sum_{v=1}^k \beta_{jv} R_{AB} x_v \right\rangle \\
\langle R_{AB} b_i, R_{AB} b_j \rangle &= \sum_{u=1}^k \sum_{v=1}^k \beta_{iu} \beta_{jv} \langle x_u', x_v' \rangle \\
\langle R_{AB} b_i, R_{AB} b_j \rangle &= \sum_{u=1}^k \sum_{v=1}^k \beta_{iu} \beta_{jv} \langle x_u, x_v \rangle \\
\langle R_{AB} b_i, R_{AB} b_j \rangle &= \left \langle \sum_{u=1}^k \beta_{iu} x_u, \sum_{v=1}^k \beta_{jv} x_v \right\rangle \\
\langle R_{AB} b_i, R_{AB} b_j \rangle &= \langle b_i, b_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}
\end{align*} $$

So the sequence $\{R_{AB} b_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq d_A}$ is also orthonormal. This also implies the image of $R_{AB}$ (which again is $\mathrm{span}(B)$) has the same dimension as its domain: $\dim(\mathrm{span}(B)) = \dim(\mathrm{span}(A)) = d_A$.

The direct sum of any vector subspace and its normal subspace is always the entire space:

$$ \mathrm{span}(A) \oplus \big(\mathrm{span}(A)\big)^\bot = \mathbb{R}^n
= \mathrm{span}(B) \oplus \big(\mathrm{span}(B)\big)^\bot $$
$$ \dim \big(\mathrm{span}(A)\big)^\bot = n-d_A = \dim \big(\mathrm{span}(B)\big)^\bot $$

So if $R_\bot : \big(\mathrm{span}(A)\big)^\bot \to \big(\mathrm{span}(B)\big)^\bot$ is any orthonormal linear transformation on those normal subspaces, we can define a corresponding transformation $R : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ on the entire domain: Any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has a unique representation as $v = v_A + v_\bot$ where $v_A \in \mathrm{span}(A)$ and $v_\bot \in \big(\mathrm{span}(A)\big)^\bot$, so define

$$ R(v) = R(v_A + v_\bot) = R_{AB} v_A + R_\bot v_\bot $$

If we combine an orthonormal basis of $\mathrm{span}(A)$ with an orthonormal basis of $\big(\mathrm{span}(A)\big)^\bot$, then $R$ maps it to another orthonormal basis, since basis elements from the same subspace are mapped by the same orthonormal transformation $R_{AB}$ or $R_\bot$; and a pairing of a basis element from $\mathrm{span}(A)$ and a basis of an element from $\big(\mathrm{span}(A)\big)^\bot$, which are perpendicular, map to an element of $\mathrm{span}(B)$ and an element of $\big(\mathrm{span}(B)\big)^\bot$, which are also perpendicular.

The other way around, any orthonormal transformation on the entire space, $R: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, uniquely determines values $x_i' = R x_i$ and a transformation $R_\bot : \big(\mathrm{span}(A)\big)^\bot \to \big(\mathrm{span}(B)\big)^\bot$ found just by restricting the domain.

If $k = n-1$, the sets of points preserve distances / inner products, and the vectors in $A$ are linearly independent, then $d_A = n-1$ and $d_\bot = 1$. There are exactly two orthonormal linear transformations $R_\bot : \big(\mathrm{span}(A)\big)^\bot \to \big(\mathrm{span}(B)\big)^\bot$, and they are an additive inverse pair. These correspond to exactly two orthonormal linear transformations $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. One of these is a rotation ($\det R = +1$) and the other is a reflection ($\det R = -1$). So there is exactly one rotation $R$ satisfying $Rx_i = x_i'$ for every $i$.

If $k < n-1$, then $d_A \leq k < n-1$, and we can augment the sequences with any unit vectors $x_{k+1} \in \big(\mathrm{span}(A)\big)^\bot$ and any $x_{k+1}' \in \big(\mathrm{span}(B)\big)^\bot$ to increase the dimension $d_A$. The augmented lists still have $\langle x_i,x_j \rangle = \langle x_i',x_j' \rangle$ since the new pairings have $\langle x_i,x_{k+1}\rangle = 0 = \langle x_i',x_{k+1}' \rangle$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. We can repeat that until $d_A = n-1$, and by the result above still have a rotation satisfying $R x_i = x_i'$ for the longer sequences. Since we could choose more than one possible values of $x_{k+1}'$ with the same value of $x_{k+1}$, this gives multiple rotations satisfying the set of just $k < n-1$ requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get the idea.  If we know how a rotation map a $n-1$ dimensional subspace then we should know how it map the whole space. In the three dimension case, if we know how a rotation map the x and y axis, then we should know how it map the z axis using the right hand rule. It is so simple!